# Thunderous throw and flanking

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle, flanking

The class Bloodstorm Blade (ToB p.100) has an ability called Thunderous Throw that states:

> ...As a swift action, you can choose to treat your ranged attack rolls with thrown weapons as melee attacks for the rest of your turn. You use your melee attack bonus, including Strength bonus, feats, and so forth, to determine your attack bonus for each attack as normal, but you apply the standard modifiers for range penalties. Attacking into melee, through cover, and so forth incurs the standard penalties. In addition, you can apply 1-1/2 times your Strength bonus to damage if you wield the thrown weapon with two hands, and you can use Power Attack with your thrown weapon attacks (adding two times the number subtracted from attack rolls as a bonus on damage rolls when throwing a twohanded weapon)."*

1. Would this allow me to flank a creature with the ranged throw?
2. If yes, is there a range limit?

Comment: Am I the only one thinking about *Island of Blades* here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/combatModifiers.htm#flanking)

> When making a melee attack, you get a +2 flanking bonus if your opponent is threatened by a character or creature friendly to you on the opponent’s opposite border or opposite corner.
>
> When in doubt about whether two friendly characters flank an opponent in the middle, trace an imaginary line between the two friendly characters’ centers. If the line passes through opposite borders of the opponent’s space (including corners of those borders), then the opponent is flanked.

Your attack is treated as a melee attack so it is eligible for the flanking bonus. To check if you're flanking you draw a line between yourself and your friend and see if it runs though opposite borders. There is no range limitation beyond what your attack otherwise states.

Comment: Then the special ability thunderous throw should actually say *...rest of your turn. **For example,** you use...*, the list being some but not all of the what the first sentence means. (Not doubting; just confirming.)